# Placing text on perspective pane

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I have the following shape and text which I'm trying to lay on the shape.

[image]

I certainly tried to put text on ground plane (not illustrated in screenshot), but I'm not able to get exactly the perspective matching to my shape's plane. Is perspective a right tool for this if yes, how to lay down my text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your shape with text onto the plane by selecting it and dragging it onto the plane using the `Perspective Selection Tool` (<kbd>Shift + V</kbd>).

To edit your text, simply double-click it to isolate it, and then edit the text.

To pick which plane you want to add you shape to, select it using the following bubble:

[image: Plane selector]

The bubble can be found in the top-left of your workspace by default.
In your case you'll want it to look like it does in the image in order to move your shape on the blue colored plane.

Note that you need to have either the  `Perspective Grid Tool` (<kbd>Shift + P</kbd>) or the`Perspective Selection Tool` (<kbd>Shift + V</kbd>) active to make select a different plane.