# How to recreate this perspective text effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, text, effects

I'd like to recreate this "increasing size text" in Illustrator or Photoshop.

Which software should is better to use?
What tool is the best?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried anything in order to recreate this effect, in fact I am asking advices

Comment: Per our guide you should avoid titles like you used and rather try to describe what you want. If you did that you would ask for "perspective". And there are myriad of tools in bothe of these softwares that are basic one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing text on perspective pane](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21710/placing-text-on-perspective-pane)

Comment: OK, I'll be more precise in my next question. Sorry for my mistake. But still can't find a valid answer in the "Placing text on perspective panel"

Comment: It looks weird since the letters width (measure) are the same throughout the transform. I would expect "distant" letters to appear shorter AND more condensed.

Answer (score 3):

One a fast answer could be "apply perspective!". But that's not the same. Horizontal dimensions have stayed intact, the stretching is vertical. Perspective affects all dimensions.

In Illustrator you can get the right result with Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort:

[image]

In the Free Distort dialog simply drag the right side corners vertically.

If you watch carefully you see that the tilted parts of N and A (=less) have got some extra twists. Original letter shapes have little knees at the tilted parts. They have become more visible. It can be avoided by using another font or by removing the intermediate nodes. For it the text must be outlined (=Type > Create Outlines) before distorting it.

The extra nodes can be removed with Delete Anchor -tool which is under the pen in Illustrator's tool palette. It's tried here:

[image]

Free Distort is a non-destructive effect. You can remove or tweak it via the Appearance panel. By applying Object > Expand Appearance you can fix the effect for other edits.

**This can be done also in Photoshop**, but it has a drawback: If the tilted parts of the letters have some knees, they get amplified like in Illustrator. They cannot be straightened beforehand with path tools because there's no such editability in Photoshop.

The right distortion can be got with effect Warp Text. The right warping style is Arc with 0% bend + some horizontal distortion.

Normal Edit > Transform > Distort nor > Warp do not work with text, the text must be rasterized for them. Rasterized text loses sharpness, so use Warp Text.

Warp Text is available when you right click the text in the layers panel. Check in the Character panel that the text is plain without engineer-style attributes such as faux-bold. They would prevent the warping.

Finally you must stretch the warped text vertically. See the result after Arc 0% bend + 80% horizontal distortion and generous vertical stretching:

[image]

Comment: It looks weird since the letters width (measure) are the same throughout the transform. I would expect "distant" letters to appear shorter AND more condensed.

Comment: @Stan The case was interesting just because the example had that weird property (=no width reductions, it differs from perspective, Photoshop's Edit > Transform > Perspective is NOT usable nor Illustrator's perspective transform)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate answer: In Adobe Illustrator, you could use envelope distort and leave the text fully editable:

The red trapezoid is on top - with a multiply transparency blend mode to make visibility easier: with the text and the trapezoid both selected, go to Menu>Object>Envelope Distort>Make with Top Object - like so:

[image]

This gives us this result, which looks a lot like your example:

[image]

But the nice thing is that the text is still live-editable *as text*, not having to be blown to outlines - so for my money, the easiest approach to get you what you need.

[image]

Comment: It looks weird since the letters width (measure) are the same throughout the transform. I would expect "distant" letters to appear shorter AND more condensed.

Comment: @Stan - agreed, but this matches OP’s example!

Comment: Agreed. Just sayin'. This begs the question of how to accommodate a more "realistic" fake perspective.

Comment: @Stan - for my own workflows, I use Affinity Photo and Affinity Designer far more than the Adobe Suite, so I'd start a document in Affinity Designer, set up my text and such, open the same document in Affinity Photo, and then go to Live Filter Layer>Perspective and set it up - not needing to get it perfect. Live Filter layer because that way its not rasterised; save and close - re-open in Affinity Designer, and go to town with design - that live filter layer will still be editable, copyable, clippable etc. and gives huge flexibility - I was just doing this a couple days ago.